# MarkLogic 9 multiple collections in the query

Tags: marklogic

How can I use cts:uris() to get uri from multiple collections in Marklogic 9. 
The query returned an empty sequence

```
let $u := cts:uris((),(),cts:and-query((cts:collection-query("/lib/info"),                               
                                       cts:collection-query("/lib/top10"),
                        cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("function"),"stats") 
                                   ))
              )
return $u
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want docs that have BOTH collections or EITHER? Using an `and-query` like you did means it will only return docs that have BOTH.  Convert that to an `or-query` and maybe wrap it all with the `and-query`.  For simplicity you can also pass a sequence to `collection-query` which will match any.  Lastly, you don't need a `let` and `return` and for a large result set getting rid of that can let the server stream instead of buffer.

```
cts:uris((),(),
  cts:and-query((cts:collection-query(("/lib/info","/lib/top10")),
                 cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("function"),"stats")
               ))
)
```